# Add a way to be notified about new events

Tags: feature-request, badges, events

A list of Stack Overflow Events is available at https://stackoverflow.com/badges/get/events. However, you need to regularly visit the page if you want to know about new events. Can you add a way to be notified when new events are added?

Some possibilities:

- an inbox message, but not everyone might appreciate those
- an RSS feed
- a profile setting to receive an email

@Sklivvz' suggestion to filter by geography is a good idea, since I'm probably not interested in events at the other side of the world.

Comment: Actually inbox messages would be perfect if one can disable them anytime.

Comment: Maybe filter by geography?

Comment: @Sklivvz Good idea, I've added it to the question.